# Open email after sending

Tags: vba, outlook

Why am I facing the below problem?

I have written a code to open sent email after sending email. The VBA code doesn't open the latest sent email but the previous one.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Dim myNamespace As NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Folder

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set myItem = myFolder.Items(myFolder.Items.Count)

    myItem.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [ask]. Adding your code as a linked screen shot is not a good practice here and makes it difficult to debug and eventually help.

Comment: The `Item` argument here is a reference to the email that was sent - you can maybe just display that

Comment: @TimWilliams no you can't, see my answer (the note). The email isn't sent before the `Application_ItemSend` event but after.

Comment: @Peh - noted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer **why** this won't work with the `Application_ItemSend` event:

`Application_ItemSend` is called **before** the email is sent. You can see that because it has a `Cancel` parameter. This means the email only gets sent if `Cancel = False` else the email is dropped.

So you just cannot display the email because it isn't sent at this time in the `Application_ItemSend` event. It gets sent after the `Application_ItemSend` is finished.

*Note: If you put a break point within the `Application_ItemSend` you will see that the "New Email" window remains open/visible until the `ItemSend` event is finished. Therefore you cannot open that email within that event.*

---

**Workaround**
You might try the following code. This creates an event for the default folder of sent items which is called when an item is added to this folder.

> A restart of Outlook might be needed after adding the code (or at least running the `Application_Startup` procedure once).

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Item.Display
End Sub
```

If the folder where your sent items are moved to is not the default Outlook sent mail folder then you need to find the right folder to set it in `Application_Startup`.

Comment: I got your point.  Please tell me how can I achieve this without itemsend event...

Comment: @Ganesh As there is no event for **after** sending an email there is no built-in way but you can try the workaround I added.